# Automatically placing citations in the correct places

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Is there any package which intelligently handles the placement of citation information relative to the citation style guide chosen?

Here is a sample paragraph:

> The report says the stream will overflow if there are too many fish (White 2). It outlines plans to build a canal to control the water (White 15). These plans describe for flood gates near the lake (White 16) and a computer-controlled system (White 20).

- If multiple page numbers to 1 particular text appear within different sentences in 1 paragraph, the page number information is collected together and displayed at the end of the paragraph:

> The report says the river will overflow if there are too many fish. It outlines plans to build a canal to control the water. These plans describe for flood gates near the lake and a computer-controlled system. (White 2, 15-6, 20)

- If the next paragraph begins with a sentence containing a citation from the same author, ibid. is used:

> The report also outlines plans to collect the fish for the zoo (ibid. 30). Brown however, offers other suggestions (3).

- If the author's name is used within the text (as above), then it is removed from the page number at the end of the sentence or paragraph (or as appropriate to the citation formation selected).

Comment: Have you looked at the `natbib` package and its capabilities? It can't do everything on your wish list, but the first one is certainly doable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An "ibidem" mechanism (request 2) is included in the [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package, e.g. in its `authoryear-ibid`, `authortitle-ibid`, and `verbose-ibid` citation styles.

To the best of my knowledge, automatic end-of-paragraph display of citations (request 1) plus removal of author names used before in the flow of text (request 3) has not been implemented in any LaTeX bibliography package so far. (It is possible, however, to pass multiple sources and/or page numbers to a citation command placed at the end of a paragraph.)